# onSavedInstance or Shared Pref?

Tags: android

I wanted to save boolean for my application to avoid the restart scenario because when the application is kept in Recent history for long time It restarts the activity.

What will be the better option sharedPre

Comment: about onSavedInstance read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/151822/1436931 good answer. I hope it will help you to decide what you want to do.